# More accurate result set in solr search

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solr4

I just implemented `apache's solr search` in our e-commerce application. I need to fine tune the search list for better user experience. I need guidance since I am new to solr search.

What I need to do is **more relevant result** or **exact result**. Say example if user types ‘pen’,  it should list

- pens
- pen stand
- pen drives (also fine but pens should be high priority)

But its displaying

- pens
- pen stands
- pen drives
- dispensers

First 3 is OK but dispensers, the word pen is present in middle of the word (dis **pen** sers) so no need to list dispensers with the pen lists. How to achieve this?

**Update-1:**

```
schema.xml
<types>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
        <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <!--Binary data type. The data should be sent/retrieved in as Base64 encoded Strings -->
        <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField" />
        <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
        <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
        <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />
        <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
        <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <!-- Text keyword -->
        <fieldType name="text_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <!-- Text path -->
        <fieldType name="text_path" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="\" replace="/" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <!--FOR AUTO SUGGESTION FIELD -->
        <fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <!-- Text Shingle -->
        <fieldType name="text_shingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="7" outputUnigrams="true"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
    </types>
    <!-- Fields definition -->
        <fields>
            <field name="unique_id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" />
            <field name="products_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
            <field name="sku" type="text_keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
            <field name="category_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
            <field name="store_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field name="website_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field name="product_status" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field name="category_path" type="text_path" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />
            <field name="textSpell" type="text_ws" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />
            <field name="textSearch" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
            <field name="textSearchText" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
            <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <!--Dynamic fields -->
            <dynamicField name="*_int" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_varchar" type="text_keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_text" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_decimal" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_datetime" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_static" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_boost" type="edgytext" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_boost_exact" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
            <dynamicField name="*_facet" type="text_keyword" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />
        </fields>
```

**Update-2:**

[solrconfig.xml](http://pastebin.com/Zj8NBiqQ)

Comment: can you share the field definition in the schema.xml?

Comment: In case you are using a (e)dismax query handler, so that you in fact are searching over several fields, please share all relevant field definitions.

Comment: @D_K Updated field defination

Comment: And against which of these fields does your search go, when `user types ‘pen’`? And how is the type definition?

Comment: @cheffe updated type definition

Comment: Sorry to repeat, but: And against which of these fields does your search go, when `user types ‘pen’`? :)

Comment: As i told am new to solr, where to find those fields?

Comment: Can copy your query? what are your q parameters? Are you typing before "pen"? Look into solrconfig.xml and see what you are doing with handler.

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/english/select?q=pen

Comment: Hi arun help me out, i strut here, where can i find the indexed fields and how can i change? how do i achieve my requirement?

Comment: When you say `q=pen` then Solr matches it with the field you have marked as default in the `select` request handler. Can you see the `select` requesthandler and tell us which filed is defaulr?

Comment: Look into your `solrconfig.xml` for `requestHandler` tags. Most likely with the attribute `class="solr.SearchHandler"`.

Comment: You also need to share the RequestHandler from solrconfig.xml which you are using for your searches

Comment: I just added `solrconfig.xml` in my question for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textSearch field of type edgytext is based on the letter-level ngrams, i.e.

In: "bicycle"

Out: "bicy", "bicyc", "icyc", "icycl", "cycl", "cycle", "ycle"

example taken from:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer

This will allow for inter-token search results, that you see. If you would like to have token-level n-grams define you search field based on text_shingle. Btw, be careful with the maxShingleSize. Value 7 seems a bit too high, it will significantly contribute to the index size.

Comment: can you explicitly define you default field in the /select handler? <lst name="defaults"><str name="df">textSearch</str></lst>

Comment: i cant see the `/select` handler in `solrconfig.xml`, where can i find it?

Comment: <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true"> line 383

Comment: btw, after changing the type of textSearch to text_shingle you need to reindex.

Comment: Hi, if i type pen, pen list should come first, like pen,pen, pen, pen,(all pens first)pens,pen drive,pen stand. But now it's displaying like pen,pens,pen,pen drive,pen, pen stand. How to group this? Any class available for this?

Comment: you can remove the duplicates by adding <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> specified after the NGramTokenizerFactory in the field definition

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest do this for best results:

1. Copy paste the text_general FieldType from [this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) and place inside the  tag of your schema.xml
2. Change this line from your current schema.xml to `<field name="textSearch" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />`
3. Restart the Solr server and the re-index the data.
4. Sample search query - `http://solr-server:8983/solr/english/select?q=pen&defType=edismax&qf=textSearch`

Comment: Hi, if i type pen, pen list should come first, like pen,pen, pen, pen,(all pens first)pens,pen drive,pen stand. But now it's displaying like pen,pens,pen,pen drive,pen, pen stand. How to group this? Any class available for this?